# How to find the limit of a sequence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, infinity

Question:

If $0 < x < \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $f_k(x) = \tan(x)+\frac{1}{2}\tan(x/2)+ ...+\frac{1}{2^k}\tan(x/2^k)$.

In Sigma Notation:
$$f_k(x) = \sum_{n=0}^k \frac{1}{2^n}\tan\frac{x}{2^n}$$

Find $$\lim_{k\to \infty}f_k(x)$$

I'm not quite sure how to take the limit of a sequence, I've never seen this before, If someone could help me solve this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a geometric seriesto me

Comment: It is not clear what you ask. You say that $0 < x < \pi/2$, and then you ask us to send $x \to \infty$. Do you want to compute the limit $$\lim_k f_k(x)$$ for all $x$ (i.e. pointwise convergence), or do you want this sequence to converge uniformly or what?

Comment: I really dont know! I have never seen a limit like this in my life before

Comment: Are you sure you copied the question right?

Comment: In a first approximation, with $\tan(x)\approx x$, the series converges to $x\sum1/4^k=4x/3$.

Comment: @Guy OK, you've never seen a problem like this. But surely you see that restricting $x$ to $(0,\pi/2)$ and then letting $x\to \infty$ makes no sense. Please, either fix the problem or delete it.

Comment: My bad guys, it is k that approaches infinity, not x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just observe that $$\tan\alpha=\cot\alpha-2\cot 2\alpha,$$ and you'll get
$$S_k=\sum_{n=0}^k \frac{1}{2^n}\tan\frac{\alpha}{2^n}=\tan\alpha+\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{1}{2^n}\cot\frac{\alpha}{2^n}-\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\cot\frac{\alpha}{2^{n-1}}=$$
$$=\tan\alpha-\cot\alpha+\frac{1}{2^k}\cot\frac{\alpha}{2^k}.$$
Since $x\cot\alpha x\to \frac{1}{\alpha}$ when $x\to 0$, the final result is $$\lim_{k\to\infty} S_k=\tan\alpha-\cot\alpha+\frac{1}{\alpha}=\frac{1}{\alpha}-2\cot2\alpha.$$

Answer (score 2):

I assuming that is $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}f_{k}\left(x\right)=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{\tan\left(x/2^{n}\right)}{2^{n}}.
 $ Using the Taylor series of tangent and cotangent we have $$\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{\tan\left(x/2^{n}\right)}{2^{n}}=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{1}{2^{n}}\sum_{m\geq1}\frac{B_{2m}\left(-1\right)^{m}2^{2m}\left(1-2^{2m}\right)}{\left(2m\right)!}\frac{x^{2m-1}}{2^{2mn-n}}=\sum_{m\geq1}\frac{B_{2m}\left(-1\right)^{m}2^{2m}\left(1-2^{2m}\right)}{\left(2m\right)!}x^{2m-1}\frac{2^{2m}}{2^{2m}-1}=
 $$ $$=-2\sum_{m\geq1}\frac{B_{2m}\left(-1\right)^{m}2^{2m}}{\left(2m\right)!}\left(2x\right)^{2m-1}=\frac{1}{x}-2\cot\left(2x\right).
 $$

Comment: Does not go to zero when $x \to 0$

Comment: @uranix Sorry what doesn't not go to zero? Where is the error in my calculation?

Comment: Your series for tan are wrong, they have negative powers of x

Comment: @uranix Fixed, thank you.