Summation till infinity of trigonometric func. $S=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}\cdot \tan\frac{\pi }{2^{k+1}}$
$$S=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}\cdot \tan\frac{\pi }{2^{k+1}}$$
Then find $|\log_{\pi} S|$
I tried doing it by taking approx. but it didn't work
The ans is 1

Similar - https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1367957/1157207

@Nic  the value of $|\log_{\pi} S|$  is 1 which means the S = $1/{\pi}$ probably
